# ModelCheckpoint in keras compare with old model

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am new to deep learning and doing some classification problems.

I use `EarlyStopping` and `ModelCheckpoint` in my callbacks list but when training is starting, the baseline of the model checkpoint is negative infinity and overwrite 'best_model.h5'.

However, 'best_model.h5' already store my last best model. I want to set the baseline of `ModelCheckpoint` to the performance of my last best model on the data.

Can anyone help me?

```
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, patience=3)
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid), batch_size=400,\
                  epochs=20, callbacks=[es, mc])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUbIp.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model-{epoch:04d}_{val_accuracy:.2f}.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', save_best_only=True, verbose=1)
```

This will save your new best model with `epoch` number and `validation_accuracy` without overwriting `best_model.h5`. This should later help you pick the best models and compare.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem was you wanted to save the val_acc before the first epoch - Back to the mechanism of a general machine learning problem, I don't think the accuracy value before the first iteration makes sense to a comparison (your model has not been trained on the given dataset). If you do want, you could check the validation loss (val_loss) if possible.

But if you want to save the log of your training process, you don't need to save model for each epoch. You could use the history function as (import matplotlib.pyplot as plt)

```
results = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid), batch_size=400,epochs=20, callbacks=[es, mc])

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.title("Learning curve")
plt.plot(results.history["loss"], label="loss")
plt.plot(results.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('loss.png')

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.title("Learning curve")
plt.plot(results.history["acc"], label="accuracy")
plt.plot(results.history["val_acc"], label="accuracy")
plt.xlabel("Epochs")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('acc.png')
```